# Use Roaming Profiles as Default in AD (running Samba)

Tags: active-directory, group-policy, samba, domain-controller

I've just set up an Active Directory Domain Controller (running Samba 4), created users, shares, groups, etc and everything is working.

However, I have an environment where the use of roaming profiles is wanted.  I can change the profile path for each user (e.g. \SERVER\PROFILES\%USERNAME%) but how can I make this the default for all accounts (including newly created accounts).

I haven't found anything on this topic and I'm wondering why nobody wants to set default profile paths for all users with no exception.

Comment: Have you tried deploying this via GPO using the "Set roaming profile path for all users logging onto this computer" policy?  GPO would be the suitable solution here unless you manually added the profile path within AD or use a third party software to automatically create accounts and populate these fields within AD.

Comment: Does this GPO include all PCs that are part of the Domain and force the users to use Roaming profiles? If so, that's the perfect solution, thanks!

Comment: You can select the GPO to apply to every PC or just a selected few, your choice. I'll post an answer which is more in-depth.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your most suitable solution would be to use group policy.  Using group policy will allow you to apply a standard path for all computers.

This policy can be set by performing the following:

1. Launch 'Group Policy Management Console' and locate the policy called 'Set roaming profile path for all users logging onto this computer'.  This is located under 'Computer Configuration\Policies\Administrative Templates\System\User Profiles'.
2. Enable this policy and set the roaming profile path:

   [image]

If you'd like more information regarding deploying roaming profiles across a domain, you can check out the TechNet article which provides further information:

[Deploying Roaming User Profiles (Microsoft TechNet)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj649079.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot. Still pretty uncomfortable setup compared to Samba 3 when it comes to roaming profiles but the Domain integration and security consistency is much, much better.